# F# on MonoDev not able to compile call to Webclient DownloadFile

Tags: f#

I have written this simple code

```
let downloadFile (wc : WebClient) (webUrl : string) (filePath : string) =
    wc.DownloadFile(webUrl, filePath) // no problem
    try
        wc.DownloadFile(webUrl, filePath) // problem!! why???
    with
    | ex -> printfn "%s" ex.Message; ()
```

Here the first call to the wc.DownloadFile compiles perfectly.

the same call when placed inside Try makes the comipler throw this error

> The member or object constructor 'DownloadFile' taking 2 arguments are not accessible from this code location. All accessible versions of method 'DownloadFile' take 2 arguments.

Again. I am trying this on monodevelop on ubuntu. Right now I don't have my windows machine to check if this works on windows F#.

Comment: It compiles fine for me using the F# 3.0 compiler.

Comment: on windows yes. I am facing this issue in monodevelop.

Comment: Oh, I forgot to mention that, that was on Linux.

Answer (score 0):

What version of Ubuntu are you working with and what version of Mono is installed on your system? What version of F#? What version of the .NET framework are you targeting?

Perhaps the implementation of `System.Net.WebClient.DownloadFile` is incomplete or buggy in your version of Mono. It could also be the runtime itself or your build of F#.

It looks complete to me but I guess it depends on when your Mono was built. You can match the dates of your runtime to the commit history of WebClient.cs to get an idea of what might be missing.

https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/System/System.Net/WebClient.cs
https://github.com/mono/mono/commits/master/mcs/class/System/System.Net/WebClient.cs

I can tell you that the problem is not MonoDevelop. It works for me in MonoDevelop and Xamarin Studio on Windows 8. Normally I am a Linux user but I only have the Windows machine at the moment. If I get time, I will test your snippet on RHEL6 tomorrow (using recent builds of Mono and F#).